# Static and dynamic binding

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005

Do you set an option to tell the compiler to statically or dynamically bind the .lib or how would you check if the .lib is statically binds with .exe?

Comment: since you mentioned .exe I take it as Windows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run depends.exe with the /Dependents flag. Here's the output for cl.exe using depends.exe with VS2010 on WinXP.

> dumpbin /DEPENDENTS cl.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Image has the following dependencies:

```
ADVAPI32.dll
KERNEL32.dll
MSVCR100.dll
mspdb100.dll
```

Image has the following delay load dependencies:

```
VERSION.dll
PSAPI.DLL
SHELL32.dll
```

Comment: @cpx: I assume you mean by "static vs. dynamic" whether it's just a static library (.lib) without a DLL required at runtime, and dynamic means that you need the corresponding DLL? If so, the answer is: Every dependency of the resulting executable is dynamic, as any statically linked library will be "baked" into your binary itself.